# Databases - What does it mean for an entity to be 'independent' exactly?

Tags: sql, database, types, entity

I have just started a course on database design and have been given a homework where one of the tasks is to list all the entity types of a fictional hospital according to this pdf: http://docdro.id/mbzdtUg.

I am struggling to figure out what should be an entity type and what should not. I will give you a basic example:

"Staff" is obviously an entity type but each of the staff have to have details regarding their qualifications and work experience. Since a staff member can have multiple qualifications and multiple work experiences these cannot be attributes... right? So should "Staff Qualification" and "Staff  Work experience" be an entity type?

According to entity definitions I have read entities should be independent and represent objects that actually exist. What does it mean for an entity to be independent exactly? The "Staff Qualification" and "Staff  Work experience" entity types would not exist if the entity type "Staff" didn't exist. Therefore they aren't independent (???) nor do they represent something that exists (physical object). Then what are they if not entity types? Should for example "Appointment" be an entity type? I am really confused... any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: Should mention that this should be following a Entity-Relationship model (ER)

EDIT 2: Example 2: A patient can be either a outpatient or a inpatient. Should I make these into 2 entity type or only 1 (Patient)?

Comment: A qualification such as a degree exists, independent of a person holding that qualification. You have to distinguish between Staff, Qualification and the linking table which is the relation of Staff to Qualification.

Comment: But if I make "Qualification" completely independent of "Staff" how will I know which qualification belongs to which staff member? The "Qualification" table has to have some sort of foreign key attribute (like "StaffID") to know what staff member to link it to.

Comment: @Schytheron I tried to answer this with the example schema picture in my post. You need to use joining table as you were suggested to create the 1:M and M:1 link

Comment: As per Vidmantas's comment, and I specified a 'linking table', which is the relationship of StaffID, QualificationID - this kind of middle linking table is very common.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're on the right track and your understanding is correct. If you foresee that Staff table can have multiple qualifications or work experiences - then qualification and work experience itself should be separated into a different entity table, so should the Appointment.

This is also where the normalization comes into place - because you could have two different staff members have the same work experience (or qualification) - then technically you don't want to just simply have a child table for Staff as that would result in a lot of data duplication. Usually, using normalization principles you would instead create a separate entity table WorkExperience where you would have all your different WorkExperiences. There would be no relationship between Staff and WorkExperiences tables. But you would also create StaffWorkExperiences table (joining table/buffer table), which would be a child of Staff (1:M) , but would also have a constraint to WorkExperiences table (M:1). So essentially you would end up with Staff table linking to StaffWorkExperiences table and the StaffWorkExperiences table in turn linking to WorkExperiences table.

Lastly, if you also have a patient table and the patient can be either outpatient or an inpatient - then that is more like a property and there is no need to have an extra table - so you would have only a patient table and then another column (PatientType or something like that) to describe this particular property.

**EDIT**
I have added an example schema of how this would look like with a joining table.
[image]

Comment: What is the name of the site/software you used to make that diagram (the last task in my homework is to make an ER-diagram and I don't know what to use)?

Comment: There is loads, the one I used https://www.quickdatabasediagrams.com/ - it is free to try, alternatively https://www.draw.io/ is completely free

Comment: Depending on the exact requirements, the links there may well be 0/1 to many, e.g. A qualification may be held by no staff member, and a staff member may have no qualifications